# Which stored procedure is used to send e-mail's in Azure?

Tags: azure

In the process of migrating the data from SQL Server 2008 to Azure. There is s stored procedure which sends email through `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`? While creating the stored procedure it throws an error that Azure that it is not possible.

Can any one please let me know which stored procedure I have to use instead of `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`?

Comment: Maybe this link will help you? https://vpolizzi.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/database-mail-on-sql-azure/

Comment: Thanks, Peter. That article was good but had concern on security aspects in production environment.